# How can I add a Webview below a label or image and scroll all elements together for both IOS and Android?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

Im developing a Xamarin.Forms application for both IOS and Android. My code in the XAML file is like this:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image HeightRequest="150" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding Post.ImageUrl}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Post.Title}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}" FontSize="20" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Post.CreatedOn}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontFamily="{StaticResource NormalFont}" FontSize="12" />
    <WebView x:Name="WebViewer" HeightRequest="500" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
        <WebView.Source>
           <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding Post.Data.Content}" />
        </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
    <Label Text="Comments" FontSize="12" />
</StackLayout>
```

When I simulate the application, only the Webview Scrolls and all the other elements stay fixed in place. Theres another similar question on Stackoverflow, but the solution doesn't work and it doesnt answer my question for IOS, it is only targetted for Android.

[This image shows the webview scrolling, and it's siblings staying in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONDKa.png)

I would like that they all scroll together so that it acts like one page. This should be a crossplatform solution, so I only have to write the code once for both IOS and Android. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add stacklayout inside scrollview and set webview height request = device screen height

Comment: @PragneshMistry can you please post a code example? i do not know how to set device screen height in xaml and webview doesnt have heightrequest attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like that

Design Side

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="XamarinTest.View.WebViewDemo">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image HeightRequest="150" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="home" />
                    <Label Text="Header"  FontSize="20" />
                    <Label Text="Subheader"   FontSize="12" />
                        <WebView  Source="http://www.google.com"   x:Name="WebViewer"  BackgroundColor="White">
                        </WebView>
                    <Label Text="Comments" FontSize="12" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Coding Side

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinTest.View
{
    public partial class WebViewDemo : ContentPage
    {
        public WebViewDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
            WebViewer.HeightRequest = height;
            WebViewer.WidthRequest = width;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! It works great, only with one problem. When the text is longer than the device height, the header and title are still fixed. Up until when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the Webview OR if i drag the header with my fingers then it scrolls the header too.

Comment: Yes, if you want to fix the header then you have to put header outside of the scrollview.